# ASP.NET MVC app is returning dates in incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf

We have multiple instances of an ASP.NET MVC app with a WCF services layer deployed to a number of servers which are all working fine.  The app is deployed to a web server (IIS), application server (WCF services hosted as a Windows service), and a database server (SQL Server 2012).

However, we recently provisioned a new set of servers to host another instance of the app and for some reasons dates are being rendered in US format, and not UK format.  We have modified regional settings on all of the servers to be set to UK, including the timezone, but still US dates are persisting.  The only way we have managed to get it to work is by using the following globalization entry in the web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

This shouldn't be necessary because this is working fine on another 8 instances of the application.

What does the web.config entry above override? My thought process is if I know what that entry overrides it should lead to the underlying configuration issue.

NOTE: After change regional settings across all three servers, IIS was restarted  as well as the WCF Windows service.

Comment: Have you compared the machine.configs across the servers?

Answer (score 0):

When the DateTime to string functions are called without specifying a culture (which is what I assume is happening somewhere), it will use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

The "How a Thread's Culture Is Determined" section here gives an overview of how the default current culture is determined. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks

By setting that configuration setting, it is able to use the first method. Without the setting it relies on the last one. Therefore, you should look to see what the user hosting the application has set as their preferred culture.

That being said, setting the culture in the web config seems to be a simpler way to enforce the culture settings than configuring each server's preferred culture.